# How can i update an array of values to my modal through foreach in yii2

Tags: yii2

i have a problem for updating values through foreach.its not giving me an error but its not updating to the database

```
public function actionLists()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
  $val = $request->get('jsonstring');  
  $val =  json_decode($val, true, 64);
    $new = $this->parseJsonArray($val);
    foreach ($new as $n){
        $mod = Menus::findOne($n['id']);   
        $mod->parent_id = $n['parent_id'];
        $mod->save();
    }
}
```

The problem is with codes in the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could by a validation problem

try with false il save this way:

```
public function actionLists()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $val = $request->get('jsonstring');  
    $val =  json_decode($val, true, 64);
    $new = $this->parseJsonArray($val);
    foreach ($new as $n){
       $mod = Menus::findOne($n['id']);   
       $mod->parent_id = $n['parent_id'];
       $mod->save(false); // this way
   }
}
```